# Struggling with MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, select

I have a couple MySQL queries to write, but actually I have no idea where to even begin with these. I am hoping some helpful soul will be able to help me out.

So, I have 2 tables. One is a vendor/product table which holds a `VENDORID` and a `PRODUCTID` only. Each product has one vendor, and each vendor may have 1 or many products on the table.

Table 2 is an orders table. It has `ORDERID, PRODUCTID, DATEADDED` and other things related to the order.

What I am trying to do is create a vendor sales report, by month.

On the first screen (in PHP) I would like to query out a list of months, for a given vendor. I would like to display the list of months, newest first, from the date of their first order in the system, up to the present time. Something like this:

```
 - December 2012
 - November 2012
 - October 2012
```

(etc)

Assuming the first order for one of their products was in October 2012.

Then, on the next page I would like to display a list of products sold that month, and the sum of the value of each order. Something like this:

```
ORDERS / SALES FOR DECEMBER

 - Tea Cosy - $25.00 
 - Door Mat - $48.00
 - Hammock - $62.00
```

(etc)

But only for that specific month. I can figure the PHP out, but dates and stuff in MySQL is my blind spot. :( Any help you can offer with those 2 queries would be greatly appreciated.

Merry christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I may not give you the complete code but rather I will give you an algorithm so you can start looking it on google the things you need

1) You must know how to use the `WHERE` Clause of SQL http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp

2) Date Processing in MySQL is quite easy you can refer into this [mySQL dateTime range Query Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935690/mysql-datetime-range-query-issue)

3) Adding with the sales per item can be a test for your algorithm skills as you can query you can add them by using PHP as I hope you know how to code PHP already

goodluck

Comment: Hi Mahan, thanks for your input. I already know WHERE syntax, but this is not overly helpful. What would be very helpful, is an example from which I can learn how to do these things. There is most likely GROUP BY and various other things that I do not understand, hence the post. :)